# django shared library/classes

Tags: python, django

Am new to django and was looking for advice where to place my shared library. Am planning on creating classes that I want to use across all my apps within the project. Where would be the best location to place them?

e.x abstract models

regards,

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Relevant http://timmyomahony.com/blog/updated-django-project-structure-or-folder-layout/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We usually set our projects up like this:

```
/site/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    /apps/
        __init__.py
        /appA/
            __init__.py
        /appB/
            __init__.py
    /lib/
        __init__.py
        /django-lib/
            __init__.py
        /shared-lib/
            __init__.py
```

Just make sure your site directory is on your python path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/site/')
```

Also, ensure that an init.py exists in site, apps, and lib so they can be treated as modules using dot notation imports (import site.lib.shared-lib)

Edit:

In answer to your question regarding your python path, it all has to do with where your 'manage.py' or equivalent file resides. If it is under the /site/ directory (next to apps and lib) then the PYTHONPATH should be fine.

You need to make sure that every directory contains an empty file called `__init__.py`. This tells Python to treat that directory as a module. See the new and improved ASCII art above.

Comment: I did the steps you mentioned but I was not able to include import a class from my app. I ignored the import sys and append to path because am testing it inside django, is this right?

Comment: @Mo see my edit for more information. If that doesn't help, can you edit your answer with the error message that you're getting?

Comment: what do you put in `./lib/django-lib/` ?

Comment: @HåkenLid I don't even remember, but we don't vendor libraries anymore. Just use virtualenv and pip :)

Answer (score 15):

What I learned from [Two Scoops of Django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-8) is that you put the shared code inside a Django app that you create on your own called `core`.

To use the `core` app then is similar to how you cross-use classes from other apps.

To learn more, go to Chapter 28 of the book titled: "What About Those Random Utilities?"

Answer (score 1):

If the shared library is going to be used in others projects as well you can make a installer using [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/introduction.html#a-simple-example).
But if it's only for the apps in the project you can take AntonioP's answer.

Remember that the root of your project (folder that contains manage.py) is always in your PYTHON_PATH when you run your django project, so you can create a folder `deps` or `dependencies` or `extra` or anything you like it that contains your shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want, you can import them if they are in the PYTHON_PATH.